# problems with alt text not appearing in source code

Tags: images, tags

I have added alt tags, title and description of all the images on my website but many do not show up when I check them in the inspect element tool in chrome or FireFox.  SEMRush states over 900 images do not have alt tags!  For example, the image on my homepage www.medispera.com

in the code it states `alt="image"` instead of the alt text appearing.  Please advise how to fix.

Comment: The fix will depend on what kind of code your theme is using to output the images with no alt attribute. Please share that code if you want it fixed.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. How do you produce these images? Are they automatically generated? Or images in your theme's template files?

Answer (score 1):

The display/use of various `<img>` attributes is up to the theme code. If the theme code does not use the info from the media item, then it will not display.

Fixing this will require digging into the theme code to figure out where the `<img>` code is generated, and then modifying that code.

Note that directly modifying theme code is not recommended, as a theme update will overwrite your changes. Best to use a Child Theme to modify theme code.